# Tooltip of reputation not changed

Tags: bug, status-completed, live-refresh, top-bar, tooltips

Reputation has been changed but not reflected on tooltip.

[image]

Comment: Probably caching. It doesn't update it if you refresh?

Comment: @JoshC updates on refresh but not dynamically.

Comment: Not a caching issue @JoshC. Reputation on top bar is updated dynamically (ajax) but not on tooltip. We have to refresh to see the updated one.

Comment: The number is changed via live refresh, the tooltip doesn't. Looks like a bug. @hims056 not AJAX, web sockets.

Comment: @Anna off topic but I must ask... is winter (bash) coming? (saw your hat ;))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.